# Laravel 6 storing data problem even though there are no errors

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I am trying to make a user able to post. I had some errors, but now I do not have any errors, but the store method does not work even though it does not show any errors.
This is the form in home.balde.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('form-store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <img class="avatar" src="images/uploads/avatars/{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="pic" width="50px">
                        <label for="ftext">
                            <input type="text" id="text" name="text" placeholder="What's happening?" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; color: white;" required>
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="ftopic">
                                    <input type="text" id="topic" name="topic" placeholder="Topic" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; color: white;" required>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <label for="fhashtag">
                                    <input type="text" id="hashtag" name="hashtag" placeholder="Hashtag" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; color: white;" required>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="text-end">
                                    <button type="submit" class="tweetBtn">Tweet</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

This is the model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tweets extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['content', 'topic', 'hashtag'];
}
```

This is HomeController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            abort(403, 'Only authenticated users can create new posts.');
        }

        $data = request()->validate([
            'content' => 'required',
            'topic' => 'required|email',
            'hashtag' => 'required'
            ]);
            
            $check = Tweets::create($data);
            return Redirect::to("form")->withSuccess('Great! Form successfully submit with validation.');
    }
```

And these are the routes in web.php

```
Route::get('form', 'HomeController@index')->name('form');
Route::post('form-store', 'HomeController@store')->name('form-store');
```

When I click submit the page will just refresh and nothing happens also in database

Comment: you don't have `name="content"`

Comment: I just added that and still the same situation

Comment: I suggest you display any validation errors that might occur, as explained in [Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: I did that and now it shows this error "The topic must be a valid email address."

Answer (score 1):

In `home.blade.php` there is no `<input name='content'>`

Since in your `HomeController` validation `topic` should be `email`. Do `type=email` so it will be `<input type="email" id="topic" name="topic" ...>`

Anyway this is how I will code In `HomeController`. Maybe you can try it.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    if (!auth()->check()) {
        abort(403, 'Only authenticated users can create new posts.');
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'content' => 'required',
        'topic' => 'required|email',
        'hashtag' => 'required'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        abort(400, 'IDK Some Validation Error');
    }
    Tweets::create($request->all());
    return Redirect::to("form")->withSuccess('Great! Form successfully submit with validation.');
}
```

Comment: then remove the `|email` in  `'topic' => 'required|email',` ... so `'topic' => 'required',`

Answer (score 0):

Check this code...

```
<label for="ftext">
     <input type="text" id="text" name="text" placeholder="What's happening?" style="background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; color: white;" required>
</label>
```

Instead of `name="text"` it should be `name="content"`

Comment: I added that and still the same situation